# Problem with a regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I want a regex that will match:

A type with an ID:

```
[Image=4b5da003ee133e8368000002]
[Video=679hfpam9v56dh800khfdd32]
```

With between 0 and n additional options separated with `@`:

```
[Image=4b5da003ee133e8368000002@size:small]
[Image=4b5da003ee133e8368000002@size:small@media:true]
```

I have this so far :

```
\[[a-zA-Z]*=[a-zA-Z0-9]*[@[a-zA-Z]*:[a-zA-Z]*]*\]
```

... but it's not matching all the cases.

Comment: This is solved, but it made me run into another problem adressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230372/getting-some-elements-in-a-string-using-a-regex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\[[a-zA-Z]+=[a-zA-Z0-9]{24}(@[a-zA-Z]+:[a-zA-Z]+)*\]
                           ^                    ^
```

You were enclosing that section with [], which as you are aware, is for a class, you just want a grouping. You should also ensure that the first match has at least one character, and it seems the id block has 24characters always, if this is the case use, {X} to define a repetition of length X.

Comment: There is still one issue: if you do this, it won't get all the options, only the last one. In the example "
[Image=4b5da003ee133e8368000002@size:small@media:true]" I can only retrieve "@media:true" when I also need size:true

Comment: That's what the trailing * is for. if you want to group the WHOLE section into one variable, another pair of round brackets are required, and add a '?:' after the opening inner parens. This will avoid creating a backreference. The next match for you should be in the next variable in the current case.

Comment: You should check the standards of ruby to see how it supports (?:data)

Comment: @nlycaroni: I'm not sure what you mean. Let's say I want to get "size:small" and "media:true" in two separate variables, how should I proceed ? This is kind of outside the scope of this question but... :)

Comment: I ended up opening another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230372/getting-some-elements-in-a-string-using-a-regex

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't the additional options be grouped (instead of brackets!) and marked optional (instead of *)? And you should use + instead of * or else an empty string would be matched.

```
\[[a-zA-Z]+=[a-zA-Z0-9]+(@[a-zA-Z]*:[a-zA-Z]*)*\]
```

Comment: Thanks you for the answer. nlucaroni was faster so he gets the check, but this is correct as well

Comment: I'd expand on that further and make both the key and value required when an optional field is present, although the OP didn't account for this in the question. `\[[a-zA-Z]+=[a-zA-Z0-9]+(@[a-zA-Z]+:[a-zA-Z]+)?\]`

Comment: ? is the wrong quantifier for (@[a-zA-Z]*:[a-zA-Z]*). There are between 0 to n additional options.

Answer (score 2):

```
\[[a-zA-Z]+=[a-zA-Z0-9]+(@[a-zA-Z]+:[a-zA-Z]+)*\]
```

You need to enclose the optional group in parentheses, not brackets.

Comment: Like I said to andidog, nlucaroni was faster so he gets the check, but this is correct as well. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
^\[\w+=\w+(@\w+:\w+)*\]$
```

I guess it should be possible to be more specific.

Comment: Interesting solution but it would also include underscores, which I don't want

Answer (score 0):

```
\[[a-zA-Z]+=[a-zA-Z0-9]+(@[a-zA-Z]+:[a-zA-Z]+)?\]
```

I think this will be little better :)